# connecting nulls in logi analytics charts

Tags: mongodb, google-analytics

I am new to LogiAnalytics. I am using Series.Line to plot a graph with values retried from MongoDB. The values are different for each date. Some times it happens that for the very first date there is no value in the MongoDB collection itself. When we create a graph, it ignores the first value which is actually not having a value and starts from the second point which has a value.

In the Series.Line there is an attribute "Connect Nulls" and we set that to "true". However it does not make any impact. Can any please help me solve this problem.

I am adding my code snippet here"

```
 <ChartCanvas
                                    AutoQuicktip="True"
                                    BorderColor="#cfcfcf"
                                    BorderColorTransparency="1"
                                    ChartBorderThickness="1"
                                    ID="lineChart"
                                    NoDataCaption="@Request.noDataDisplay~"
                                    SpacingLeft="50"
                                    SpacingRight="50"
                                    >
                <Series  ChartXDataColumn="dateCalculatedColumn"    
 ChartXDataColumnType="DateTime"    ChartYDataColumn="count" 
 ConnectNulls="True"            
 ID="engagementSeriesLine" Type="Line"
                                        >
                                        <DataLayer
                                            ConnectionID="connMetrics"
                                            ID="dlLineGraph"
                                            MongoRunCommand="{  
//My query here
}"
                                            Type="MongoRunCommand"
                                            >
                                            <CalculatedColumn
                                                Formula="(new  
Date(@Data.day~).getMonth()+1)+&quot;/&quot;+new 
Date(@Data.day~).getDate()+&quot;/&quot;+new Date(@Data.day~).getFullYear()"
                                                ID="dateCalculatedColumn"
                                            />
                                            <CrosstabFilter
                                                CrosstabColumn="network"

CrosstabLabelColumn="dateCalculatedColumn"
                                                CrosstabValueColumn="count"
                                                CrosstabValueFunction="sum"
                                                ID="rdCrosstabValue"
                                            />
                                        </DataLayer>
                                    </Series>
                                    <ChartXAxis
                                        AxisType="DateTimeLinear"
                                        ScaleLowerBound="@Request.stDate~"
                                        ScaleUpperBound="@Request.edDate~"
                                        >
                                        <AxisLabelStyle
                                            Format="MM/dd"
                                        />
                                    </ChartXAxis>
                                </ChartCanvas>
```

Request you to please help.

Comment: This problem is still not solved for us. I guess this has been solved in the latest version if released

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, If it is a bug in Logi, especially one they've fixed in a newer version, you're only real solution is to update the version you are running. Luckily that's pretty easy to do, it just requires some regression testing to make sure your existing application isn't going to have any issues.